# Unable to open existing project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, illegalargumentexception

I am getting this error while opening existing project from android studio.

> IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1 android studio

I have android studio 2.1 Preview 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue with your version of android studio.

It happens when no SDK installed, or no remote reports found!!

Or

When sites are hosting SDK downloads are not online!

There is a temporary and easy fix, but after you do the fix ....update your studio using the update option in the launch window.

1. Go to your Android Studio directory and locate the "bin" folder.
2. Inside you will find a file "idea.Properties", open it using any text editor like Notepad!
3. Inside the file add this line, "disable.android.first.run=true" Without the quotes. This is make your studio start. Update it from the start page.

Finally, you should check whether JDK installed or not if it's installed then check whether it's for 32 or 64-bit machine. Install JDK and save its directory in the path (Advance System Setting > Environment Variables > Scroll down and look for a path in the first tab > Edit it > Paste java jdk->bin directory path there and do not put; at the end of line > Save > Run you android studio again. )